# Facebook authentication strategy with Passport.js, Express and TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm trying to set up the Facebook authentication strategy on my app using Passport.js, Express and TypeScript. I could understand the dataflow of the process thanks to [this article from Hacker Noon](https://hackernoon.com/passportjs-the-confusing-parts-explained-edca874ebead).

But when it comes to the verification callback function, things get a little troublesome. I need to check whether the user is already logged in, thus the access to the Request object is necessary. I've checked in the `passport-facebook` module docs that `passReqToCallback: true` can be set on the strategy options to enable this.

However when I pass the `req` parameter to the callback function, the compiler throws the following error:

```
Argument of type '(req: Request, accessToken: string, _refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VerifyFunction'.
```

Looking around the type definitions of the Passport.js module I found this:

```js
export type VerifyFunction =
    (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: (error: any, user?: any, info?: any) => void) => void;

export type VerifyFunctionWithRequest =
    (req: express.Request, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: (error: any, user?: any, info?: any) => void) => void;

export class Strategy implements passport.Strategy {
    constructor(options: StrategyOptionWithRequest, verify: VerifyFunctionWithRequest);
    constructor(options: StrategyOption, verify: VerifyFunction);

    name: string;
    authenticate(req: express.Request, options?: object): void;
}
```

So, in theory, the declaration

```js
new Strategy(fbConfig, (req: Request, accessToken: string, _refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: any) => { ... });
```

should be accepted with no problems.

Here is the full `fbConfig` declaration:

```js
const fbConfig = {
  clientID: "",
  clientSecret: "",
  callbackURL: "",
  passReqToCallback: true,
  profileFields: [
    "id",
    "name",
    "birhday",
    "gender",
    "email",
    "location",
    "hometown"
  ]
};
```

And my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "@models/*": ["./src/models/*"],
      "@configs/*": ["./src/configs/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["./src/controllers/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

---

If anyone could help me out with this, I'd appreciate it pretty much!

Comment: Just to remove the obvious one make sure you import { Request } from "express" and not use typescript's standard library type-definition of Request

Comment: Oh, yeah. I'm definitely doing that. I suffered a lot for this mistake before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried what [Shanon Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7428434/shanon-jackson) recommended, but it didn't work. The compiler couldn't recognize the overloaded constructor for the `Strategy` class.

So what I did was:

```js
new Strategy(
  fbConfig as StrategyOptionWithRequest, 
  (
    req: Request,
    accessToken: string,
    _refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done
  ) => { ... }
);
```

I suppose that casting the `fbConfig` object to `StrategyOptionWithRequest` forced the compiler to use the constructor that expected that interface. Then I annotated the types of the callback function parameters, but left `done` to the compiler inference system to deal with. Annotating it to `any` seemed to mess a bit with VSCode's IntelliSense system, making it do not display `done`'s expected parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript actually has a NodeJS starter kit with Facebook OAuth completely setup so people can observe how it's implemented here:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter
And you can find their passport implemented with Facebook here:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/src/config/passport.ts

It Looks like they are casting "Request" to `any` i suspect it's because of conflicting definitions of `Request` between express/passport/Typescript standard library but can't know for sure

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The way they cast the request object is a bit weird to me, but I'm gonna try it. Hope it works.

Comment: So, it didn't work, despite the mentioned starter project works without a flaw. But I could find a work around. I'm gonna post an answer.